# Restore form from secondary form

Tags: c#

I have a form that minimizes when I open a secondary form (using a button click event). I want to be able to restore the original form when closing the secondary form. I have not been able to figure out how to restore the original. Here is the code I have (in example form)
The code from the main form:

```
private void BtnSecondaryForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Open the secondary form.
        FrmSecondaryForm fsf = new FrmSecondaryForm ();
        fsf.Show();
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
```

Code from the secondary form:

```
private void FrmSecondaryForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // I need this code to be able to restore the main form.
    }
```

Please don't just redirect me to someone else's similar question without explaining how I can get this to work in my application. I have looked at the other similar questions here on Stack Overflow already and don't understand how to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *find* the form you want or restore, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

private void FrmSecondaryForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   var mainForm = Application
    .OpenForms
    .OfType<MainForm>()
    .LastOrDefault();

  if (mainForm != null) {
    mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work the way I originally wanted to, which is to hide the main form. In the main form event handler for the button that opens the secondary form, I changed the this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized; to this.Hide(); and then change the mainForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; to mainForm.Show();  I have been searching for a way to hide the main form and then have it be shown when closing the secondary form but assumed that I would need to settle for minimizing the main form.

Comment: On a related side note: I also found that the FormClosing and FormClosed events don't fire if using this.Hide() to close the secondary form. Instead I needed to use the this.Close() to get the event handler to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Move `FormClosing` event handler to primary form. This form is interested in the event anyway. I also changed event from FormClosing to FormClosed. Former can be called many times, but latter is called only once, when the form is actually closed.

```
private FrmSecondaryForm Fsf = null;

private void BtnSecondaryForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Open the secondary form.
    Fsf = new FrmSecondaryForm();
    Fsf.Show();
    Fsf.FormClosed += PrimaryForm_SecondaryFormClosed;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}

private void PrimaryForm_SecondaryFormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Fsf.FormClosed -= PrimaryForm_SecondaryFormClosed;
    Fsf.Dispose();
    Fsf = null;

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you need Form2 to interact with Form1, which means that Form2 needs a reference to it.

Best is to do this during construction.  But with forms, you should always keep a default no-parameter constructor, so we need to add a new one and make the original private.

```
//Add a new property (or field if you wish)
private Form formToMinimise { get; }

//Change this to be private
private SecondaryForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}       

//Add this new constructor as public
public SecondaryForm(Form form): this()
{
   formToMinimise = form;
}
```

Now closing and restore original.  We do a null check, just in case

```
private void FrmSecondaryForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    formToMinimise?.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal ;
}
```

Now you amend the creation and calling of your second form like this

```
private void BtnSecondaryForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create the secondary form with reference to this form
    FrmSecondaryForm fsf = new FrmSecondaryForm(this);
    fsf.Show();

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
}
```